# jquery iterate through divs correct order wont work?

Tags: jquery, iteration

i am using a plugin to reorder divs. I have this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ncz3bajq/).
If you reorder the divs the console.log will always show the initalial order. But i like to iterate throught the divs in the order of the page.

Here you can see how i try to iterate:

```
$(".brick").each(function(index, domEle) {
            var id = $(domEle).attr("id");
            console.log(index + ': ' + id);  
        });
```

Comment: The issue is because the elements have been reordered in terms of their position on the screen. In the DOM tree they remain in the original order. I would expect the library which provides the sorting logic to have a method.property to return you back the new order. From the [documentation](https://github.com/ksylvest/jquery-gridly) (or shocking lack thereof in this case) it appears gridly doesn't provide this feature. I'd suggest finding a better alternative library

Comment: Do you know a library which can solve the problem?

Comment: If you use jQueryUI sortable it has a `toArray()` method which does exactly what you're asking for: https://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#method-toArray